# Layout xml tools:targetApi not working

Tags: android, xml, layout

I use https://github.com/mattprecious/swirl/blob/master/README.md in my app.
I don't want appear SwirlView on lowwer sdk marshmallow version. because SwirlView working on version sdk marshmallow or higher version.

so I add "tools:targetApi='M'" to SwirlView xml node. look at the code below.

```
<com.mattprecious.swirl.SwirlView
    android:id="@+id/fingerprint_SwirlView"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    tools:targetApi="M"/>
```

but when I run app on lolipop version. occure error like this.

```
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #29: Error inflating class com.mattprecious.swirl.SwirlView
```

what is problem with my code.
sorry for my poor english skill.

Answer (score 0):

You gotta override the xml instead of suppressing the error. Tools don't affect the app, only Android Studio.